# Google Analytics API For getting total clicks and impression on element

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am really new to Google Analytics and I had a requirement of tracking clicks and impressions. I followed following link

http://www.statstory.com/tracking-clicks-and-impressions-in-google-analytics/

and sucessfully implemented the same.

> Now my requirement is to get the no.of clicks and no. of impressions
>   to my html page. I am googled for past quite hours but couldnot find
>   any luck with the same.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you thought about using enhanced e-commerce to gather impressions and clicks instead? Following that guide is quite old as it uses legacy, or Classic Analytics, code. Did you follow the guide but updated it to Universal?

Comment: Enhanced e-commerce is a feature within Google Analytics. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce. Anyhow, if you have successfully implemented above, then can't you just access the event category, action and label events from the API to pull the data you need? Should be quite straight forward.

Comment: When you say "to my html page", do you want to show the results (i.e. total clicks and impressions) on your page?

Answer (score 1):

You should really consider implementing Google Analytics Enhanced E-commerce functionality.

[Google Analytics Enhanced E-commerce](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce)

In regards to answering your question of the API, you should query it asking for events. Namely category, action and label events and apply a filter to only return the data you wish to receive, such as 'Impressions' as a filter for 'Event Action'. That will return all impressions and if you instead change the filter to use 'Click', you'd get all clicks instead.

If you followed the above guide and made it into Universal, then you'd see the calls you set and it is set up in the following way:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Banner', 'Click', 'BANNERNAME',1.00,true]);
```

This bit of code pushes (legacy version) Analytics data in the form of:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Category', 'Action', 'Label',1.00,true]);
```

So, changing the different sections means you change how you define the data and how it will be visible in reports. Category defines the Event Category, Action defines the Event Action and Label defines the Event Label.

Take a look at the [core development guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide). Also, here you can see all the API calls available: [Dimension & Metrics explorer for Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=event_tracking)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will this out.

Answer (score 1):

I gather that you want to track impressions for banner advertising that is displayed by yourself (i.e. not through an adserver) in your website.

I agree with Mr Sponge that you should upgrade to Universal Analytics. if you want to implement enhanced  e-commerce tracking (EEC) you probably want to read about [Measuring internal Promotions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#action-types), which is a feature specifically build for that kind of reporting.

If you just need the raw number of banner impressions and/or need a solution that's easier to implement (but less capable) you can increment a c[ustom metric](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en) every time you banner shows up (this is basically a counter, you might want to use it together with a custom dimension that holds the banner name). Click tracking would still be done by events (with similar custom metrics and dimensions). From that data you can assemble a custom report and use a calculated metric for click through rates etc.

Not as good as EEC by a fair margin but much easier to do.